# Visual Studio 2017 not detecting change in .cu (CUDA) files

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have Visual Studio 2017 and Cuda Toolkit 9.1 installed. It is working, I confirmed it by building a few projects.

Now when I edit a .cu file and press build. It says that the project is already up to date. It is only possible to build the changes into the new binary, when using rebuild.

Comment: Have you added the relevant files/projects to configuration manager? (`build -> configuration manager`)

Comment: I have the same problem using vs2017, cuda 9.1 and toolset v140. please inform me, if you got a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

A work around is to force a Compile instead of a build using  `Build -> Compile` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> instead.
This fixed the issue for me, but also please note I initially tried `Build -> Run Code Analysis on File` (which also worked) before subsequently adopting the aforementioned workaround.

Answer (score 1):

After filing a bug report at NVidia, they resolved the ticket in the next working day,  promising to deliver the fix with the next release of Nsight Visual Studio. (I'm currenty using Nsight Visual Studio 6.0 which came with CUDA 10.0.)

I'm looking forward to try out the new release (whenever it comes out) and I'm pleasantly surprized by the speed of their response.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft modified the way in VS 2017, how source code changes are detected.

A solution is written from chrispy81 on the [Nvidia Developer Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029759/cuda-setup-and-installation/visual-studio-2017-not-detecting-changes-in-cuda-cu-files/2).

```
In the CUDA 10.0.targets files:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.0.targets" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.0.targets" 
"c:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions\CUDA 10.0.targets" 

under this tag:

<WriteLinesToFile
    Condition="'%(CudaCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'"
    File="%(CudaCompile.DepsOutputPath)"
    Lines="@(_CudaCompileDeps)"
    Overwrite="true" />

write this:

<PropertyGroup>
    <CudaCompileItemFullPath>%(CudaCompile.FullPath)</CudaCompileItemFullPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<GetOutOfDateItems
    Condition ="'$(SelectedFiles)' == ''"
    Sources ="%(CudaCompile.FullPath);
    @(_CudaCompileDeps)"
    OutputsMetadataName ="Outputs"
    DependenciesMetadataName ="AdditionalInputs"
    CommandMetadataName ="Command"
    TLogDirectory ="$(TLogLocation)"
    TLogNamePrefix ="%(CudaCompile.Filename)%(CudaCompile.Extension)$(CudaCompileItemFullPath.GetHashCode())">
    <Output TaskParameter="OutOfDateSources" ItemName="CudaBuildCoreOutOfDateItems"/>
</GetOutOfDateItems>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good News!
This problem has been addressed and is available with the CUDA 10.1 Toolkit, released in February 2019.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Sorry for the long wait.